# JBoss get max post size

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss

While I have managed to increase the max post size on my JBoss following
http://www.mastertheboss.com/web/jboss-web-server/configuring-wildfly-upload-file-size/
now I'd like my webapp to inform users. So I would like to render on the screen that the server accepts upload up to XXX MB.

How can a webapp retrieve the max post size setting from JBoss? Is there even a container agnostic way that could work across different servlet containers?

Answer (score 1):

The `max-post-size` [allows for an expression](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/server/http-listener/index.html#attr-max-post-size). That means you could use a system property which could be set on the attribute and retrieved by your application.

In CLI you'd do something like this:

```
/system-property=max.post.size:add(value=25485760)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default/:write-attribute(name=max-post-size,value=${max.post.size:10485760})
```

While the default, `:10485760`, is not strictly required, I'd advise it.

Then in your application you simply just to simply retrieve the system property.

Comment: This could be a workaround in case there is no way of getting the value directly. Yet I still hope there is.

Comment: There's not without using WildFly specific API's.